# Iterating over Periods of Time in an Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web-applications, iterator, each

Lets set an array of hashes

```
@valid_periods = Array.new
```

I want to be able to set a period of time between an "active=true" and a "active = false" state; if true is detected between the attribute(active) of two models (duty_status); then a period of time (@valid_periods) is generated.

If there is no partner of one "true" valued model (duty_status); then the partner would be the period up to DateTime.now

```
@valid_periods = Array.new
@my_duty_statuses.each do |duty_status_start|
  end_period = DateTime.now
  if duty_status_start[:active] == true
    start_period = duty_status_start.date_of_effectivity
    @my_duty_statuses.each do |duty_status_end|
      if duty_status_end[:active] == false
        end_period = duty_status_end.date_of_effectivity
        break
      end
    end
    @valid_periods.push({:start_period => start_period, :end_period => end_period})
  end
end
```

For simplification its to check the period of time where the duty status of an employee was active an inactive.

```
2011-01-31 08:26:28 +0800 | true 
2014-03-03 13:26:28 +0800 | false 
2016-01-22 18:25:42 +0800 | true
```

Is supposed to look like:

```
Date Start                  Date End
2011-01-31 08:26:28 +0800   2014-03-03 13:26:28 +0800
2016-01-22 18:25:42 +0800   DateTime.now
```

But what i am getting is this:

```
Date Start                  Date End
2011-01-31 08:26:28 +0800   2014-03-03 13:26:28 +0800
2016-01-22 18:25:42 +0800   2014-03-03 13:26:28 +0800
```

Why am I getting 2014-03-03 13:26:28 +0800 ? How come end_period is not being overwritten in line 3? I've tried putting it in multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question why you have the `end_period` same all the time.
You itterate `@my_duty_statuses` and in this itteration you itterate the same thing from begining of the Array. So you always have same result (2014-03-03 13:26:28 +0800).

its like this

```
arr, export = [true, false, true], []
arr.each { |bol|
  end_period = "true"
  if bol
    arr.each_with_index { |bol_2, i|
      unless bol_2
        puts "False on index(#{i})"
        end_period = "false"
        break
      end
    }
    export << end_period
  end
}
# False on index(1)
# False on index(1)
export
# => ["false", "false"]
```

If you whant to set the first "false" to last "true" so, you can use something like this itteration.

```
@valid_periods = []
@my_duty_statuses.each { |obj|
  if obj[:active]
    @valid_periods << {:start_period => obj.date_of_effectivity.to_s, :end_period => DateTime.now.to_s}
  else
    @valid_periods[-1][:end_period] = obj.date_of_effectivity.to_s
  end
}
```

Maybe this can help you.